# Ubuntu/Linux or Node.js based method of sending emails

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, smtp, exchange-server

I have an internal network smtp server that I need to go through to send emails. I've gotten it to work with [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) but it appears to fail after the greeting, with the "error" message below. It's responding with 250, so I'm not sure why it's not sending, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a Linux/Ubuntu based library I can use to accomplish this task via the CLI.

```
Server responded with 250-hostname Hello [ip]
250-TURN
250-SIZE
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
250-X-EXPS=LOGIN
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN
250-X-LINK2STATE
250-XEXCH50
250 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Um, that's not an error.  `250` is a status code that means ok.  What you have listed is the server's response to your `EHLO` command.  Each line that start with `250` lists an extended SMTP feature that your server supports.

Next step?  If authorization is required, send an `AUTH` command.  If not, start a mail transaction using `MAIL`, `FROM`, and `DATA`.

I think before proceeding you should take some time to read up on the basics of SMTP.  Then this would make more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer this, but make sure to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.

JimBastard on IRC (aka Marak), is the creator of [node_mailer](https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer), an alternative, so he'd be the guy to message, though other people might be able to help you too.